# Need help on Jest / Vue2 configuration issue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, unit-testing, jestjs, babeljs

I've a error i'm trying to solve for 2 days now without success !

I wanted to add some front unit testing on a Laravel mix + Vue 2 project with Jest.

So i've installed this in my package.json:

```
{
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "test": "jest",
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@inertiajs/inertia": "^0.11.0",
    "@inertiajs/inertia-vue": "^0.8.0",
    "@inertiajs/progress": "^0.2.7",
    "vue": "^2.6.14",
    "vue-i18n": "8"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.18.5",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.18.2",
    "@vue/test-utils": "^1.1.3",
    "@vue/vue2-jest": "^27.0.0-alpha.2",
    "axios": "^0.21",
    "babel-core": "7.0.0-bridge.0",
    "babel-jest": "^27.0.6",
    "design-system": "git+ssh://****",
    "eslint": "^8.8.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.3.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^8.4.0",
    "jest": "^27.0.5",
    "laravel-mix": "^6.0.6",
    "lodash": "^4.17.19",
    "prettier": "2.5.1",
    "resolve-url-loader": "^5.0.0",
    "sass": "^1.51.0",
    "sass-loader": "^12.6.0",
    "vue-loader": "^15.9.7",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.14"
  }
}
```

this in my babel.config.json:

```
{
  "presets": [
    "@babel/preset-env"
  ]
}
```

and this in my jest.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
  testEnvironment: 'jsdom',
  verbose: true,
  // tell Jest to handle `*.vue` `*.json` `*.js`  files
  moduleFileExtensions: ['js', 'json', 'vue'],
  testMatch: ['**/tests/**/*.[jt]s?(x)', '**/?(*.)+(spec|test).[jt]s?(x)'],
  moduleNameMapper: {
    '^@/(.*)$': '<rootDir>/resources/js/$1',
  },
  transform: {
    '.*\\.(js)$': '<rootDir>/node_modules/babel-jest',
    // process `*.vue` files with `vue-jest`
    '.*\\.(vue)$': '<rootDir>/node_modules/@vue/vue2-jest',
  },
};
```

I started to write some tests for my atoms components and everything was fine !
Jest was doing his job.

Then I started to test my molecules components, most of them import components from a dependency "design-system" (internal ressources) and when i try to test a component who import something from the design system i get this error when i type:

`yarn test`

```
 FAIL  tests/Front/organisms/Filters.spec.js
  ● Test suite failed to run

    Jest encountered an unexpected token

    Jest failed to parse a file. This happens e.g. when your code or its dependencies use non-standard JavaScript syntax, or when Jest is not configured to support such syntax.

    Out of the box Jest supports Babel, which will be used to transform your files into valid JS based on your Babel configuration.

    By default "node_modules" folder is ignored by transformers.

    Here's what you can do:
     • If you are trying to use ECMAScript Modules, see https://jestjs.io/docs/ecmascript-modules for how to enable it.
     • If you are trying to use TypeScript, see https://jestjs.io/docs/getting-started#using-typescript
     • To have some of your "node_modules" files transformed, you can specify a custom "transformIgnorePatterns" in your config.
     • If you need a custom transformation specify a "transform" option in your config.
     • If you simply want to mock your non-JS modules (e.g. binary assets) you can stub them out with the "moduleNameMapper" config option.

    You'll find more details and examples of these config options in the docs:
    https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration
    For information about custom transformations, see:
    https://jestjs.io/docs/code-transformation

    Details:

    /****/****/*****/****/*****/*****/node_modules/design-system/src/index.js:2
    export { library } from "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core";
    ^^^^^^

    SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'

      22 |
      23 | <script>
    > 24 | import { Select as ObsSelect } from 'design-system';
         | ^
      25 |
      26 | export default {
      27 |   name: 'Filters',

      at Runtime.createScriptFromCode (node_modules/jest-runtime/build/index.js:1728:14)
      at Object.<anonymous> (resources/js/components/molecules/Filters.vue:24:1)
      at Object.<anonymous> (tests/Front/organisms/Filters.spec.js:2:1)
```

You must want to see the test file and the component as well:

```
import { shallowMount } from '@vue/test-utils';
import Filters from '@/components/molecules/Filters';

describe('Filters.vue', () => {
  it('his visible', () => {
    const wrapper = shallowMount(Filters);
    expect(wrapper.isVisible()).toBe(true);
  });
});
```

```
<template>
  <div class="d-flex flex-column flex-lg-row filters">
    <obs-select
      id="country"
      v-model="filters.byCountry"
      class="pl-4 mr-lg-4"
      :disabled="true"
      :options="countryList"
      :label="$t('filters.labels.country')"
      @input="$emit('filterCountryUpdate', filters.byCountry)"
    />
    <obs-select
      id="time"
      v-model="filters.byTime"
      class="pl-4"
      :options="timeList"
      :label="$t('filters.labels.time')"
      @input="$emit('filterTimeUpdate', filters.byTime)"
    />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { Select as ObsSelect } from 'design-system';

export default {
  name: 'Filters',
  components: {
    ObsSelect,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      filters: {
        byCountry: 'all',
        byTime: this.$route().params.period || 'year',
      },
      countryList: [
        {
          value: 'all',
          text: this.$t('filters.countries.all'),
        },
        {
          value: 'US',
          text: this.$t('filters.countries.us'),
        },
        {
          value: 'DE',
          text: this.$t('filters.countries.de'),
        },
      ],
      timeList: [
        {
          value: 'year',
          text: this.$t('filters.time.year'),
        },
        {
          value: 'months',
          text: this.$t('filters.time.months'),
        },
      ],
    };
  },
};
</script>

<style lang="scss">
.filters select {
  padding-right: 75px;
  min-width: 207px;
}
</style>
```

Any idea ?

Thank you in advance for your help :)